# WordPress Underscores Theme Site Title Not First

Tags: wordpress, themes, underscores-wp

The most recent Underscores theme seems to post the Page Title first then the Site Title afterwards. How can I change this to have the Site Title first?

Answer (score 1):

Open your **header.php** theme file

Add:

```
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> &raquo; Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
```

[image: header.php]

You can remove `&raquo;` which looks like: » ( It's upto you )

---

Underscores theme is using add_theme_support() in order to support title tag as introduced in the wordpress version 4.1 and as they also mentioned in the **functions.php**

```
/*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
     * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
     * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
```